# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION after build a windows self-contained application with jdeps + jlink + jpackage

Tags: java, maven, jlink, jpackage, jdeps

I'm trying to build a bundle (self-contained app) for `windows` using `jdeps` + `jlink` + `jpackage`.

On mac, with the same procedure, I managed to create (following [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX) as reference) a fully working self-contained ".app" for this project [graph-editor](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/graph-editor/tree/777ecd1dcc3c6a8adc68af5c7682a6419f06b7fa) through a combination of `maven` and a script which uses `jdeps` + `jlink` + `jpackage`.

I expected that the same configurations for `jdeps` + `jlink` + `jpackage` would have worked on windows after the installation of [wix 3.x](https://wixtoolset.org/).

The procedure works fine and produces an installer, but unfortunately I get the error below when I launch the ".exe" file.

- More details about my configurations that I used can be found [here](https://github.com/eckig/graph-editor/issues/4).
- The "bat" script that I used is this one: [build_app.bat](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/graph-editor/blob/777ecd1dcc3c6a8adc68af5c7682a6419f06b7fa/demo/build_app.bat).
- Running a `maven install` on the [main project](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/graph-editor/tree/777ecd1dcc3c6a8adc68af5c7682a6419f06b7fa) on a windows it's possible to replicate the problem.

---

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=16672, tid=5124
#
# JRE version:  (15.0+36) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15+36, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
```

The full ".log" print can be found [here](https://github.com/eckig/graph-editor/issues/4#issuecomment-710043454).

Comment: Looks like you're using zulu. Have you tried it with other JDK distributions as well?

Comment: No I have not, I chose that one because it has included the javafx. I'll try with another JDK, I think that is a good path to try.

Comment: Yeah, it worked!
I have tried with a "Liberica Full JDK" (that includes the javafx too) and it worked immediately!

Comment: I'll leave the link for other people who will have the same problem https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-15-current

Answer (score 2):

Copy `zip.dll` from `{your app path}/runtime/bin/` to `{your app path}`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solution will fit any other person who will meet the same problem, but for me it was fine to simply switch the JDK used to a [Liberica JDK](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-15-current).